# parse multiple levels of document.write nesting

Tags: javascript, parsing, document.write

The question is a bit weird, but I am trying this just for learning purpose.

I have this string

```
var str = "document.write('<script>document.write(\"<script>document.write('<script>document.write(\"Hello World\");<\/script>');<\/script>\");<\/script>')";
```

And, I am trying to parse/eval this string so that the inner most `document.write` prints "Hello World". Here's what I tried.

```
function (str) {
    str = str.replace(/["']/g, '"')
        .replace(/"<script>document.write/g, "")
        .replace(/;<\/script\>"/g, "");
    eval(str);
}
```

But, this looks like horrible cheating. I want to do it a more subtle way. for example escaping the `\`s or splitting `</script>` tags. But can't just simply escape backslashes, as the number of slashes would need to be more for deeper nesting.

Any ideas?